# How to get next redirected url in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to StackOverflow so I will try my best to describe the problem.

I am at the page of https://www.google.com/ and you know there is the search button. I typed my query and clicked the search button using selenium. So it will take some time.
I want to get the URL after finished the search.
That exactly means how to get the URL of a page after it got loaded. Because let me explain...

1. A page having a captcha. I have to fill and click on submit
2. If the captcha is right then it will open another URL in the URL bar.
3. But if the captcha is wrong then it will stay on the same URL
4. So I wanted to know the captcha is worked or not
5. If the captcha worked then it definitely goes to the next URL.

I tried:

```
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.url_changes('https://www.mystaticurl.com/aftercaptchafilled'))
        print('Captcha Accepted')
    except TimeoutException:
        print('[Captcha Error : Solving captcha code]')
        self.Fill_captcha_function()
```

But it is not working. It still shows captcha is filled
Anyone, please?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

After your action, please get the current url using following method,

```
driver.current_url
```

Comment: it works.Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto what Jayanth said, I personally used this method.

```
current = driver.current_url
failed = "https://www.google.com"
if current == failed:
    print("Still same url!")
if current != failed:
    print("New url!")
```

You could also do

```
 driver.get("google.com")
 old = driver.current_url
 "captcha code here"
 new = driver.current_url
 if new == old:
     print("did not work :(")
 if new != old:
     print("YAY it worked :)")
```